# Center align multiple objects within a grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In illustrator CC I want to center align multiple objects (such as crosses and circles) within a grid (for example 3 x 3) ie I want my artboard to look like this:

[image]

Should I use a grid for this? If so I have set up a grid (in Edit / preferences / Guides and grid) but I don't know how to center align a particular object (for example a green circle) to a particular grid square (for example center align a green circle to the top left grid square). Any ideas please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You cannot find the menu item or you don't know how to set up the grid?

Comment: @Luciano I have added detail - is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set up your grid (**Preferences → Guides & Grid**)
2. Turn on grid snapping (**View → Snap to Grid**)
3. Draw your shapes...

[image]